# How to store authentication cookie in a Windows Store App?

Tags: javascript, cookies, webview, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a Windows Store Application (Javascript + HTML).
It provides a login form (local) and posts the user/pwd via a WebAPI call to the server.
If user/pwd is matched, the server returns an authentication cookie (Forms Authentication).

My questions are:

- How to store this cookie?
- And how to pass this cookie back in further WebAPI calls?
- There is a embedded WebView control in one page, how to pass the cookie to WebAPI calls in the WebView?

Thanks.